# html5 draw img only displays top 1/4 of the image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to simply load an image into canvas, but it only loads the top 1/4 of the image at the moment irregardless of the image being used. Any assistance appreciated.
The code is as follows :-

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };
     img.src = 'img/test.jpg';
```

Comment: Is your canvas big enough to fit the image? I don't see you setting `canvas.width` or `canvas.height`.

Comment: you sir are a Gent.
It was exactly that, for some reason I decided I could set it in css.

Comment: Ah yes - in CSS you would be setting the size of the rendered canvas, but you weren't setting the size of your drawing area :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting correct comment to answer:

You don't seem to have defined `canvas.width` or `canvas.height` (this can also be done in the HTML with `<canvas width="..." height="..."></canvas>` if desired)

Setting the canvas's width and height via CSS will stretch your drawing area to cover the target size, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify the different parameters used by the function. The function will draw FROM an image to your canvas, so the Width and Height property should be set manually to ensure that no default values are used.

`drawImage(Img, Sx, Sy, Swidth, Sheight, X, Y Width, Height)`

All of these parameters are available and should be used when possible.

Comment: If this were required, then the parameters wouldn't be optional, now would they?

Comment: Yeah I understand. 1 year ago I made a small game engine using canvas, and I ran into a problem where some of the images I would print wouldn't be of the correct size. I then took the time to specify these optional parameters and it fixed the problem. When I tried to understand why, I saw that the default values were not correct. It might have only been a bug on my side though.

Answer (score 0):

As Niet the Dark Absol says you need to set the canvas to fit your image.

```
img.onload = function() {
  context.canvas.width = img.width;
  context.canvas.height = img.height;
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };
```